# Ionic build has begun failing with `Function expressions are not supported in decorators`

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have been running [an open source project](https://github.com/jrquick17/ionic4-auto-complete) that has suddenly begun failing builds. I have read through countless answers on SO (with similar error messages but not a working solution) and GitHub threads on the issue and have not been able to pinpoint the problem.

When I run `ionic build --prod` I get an error resulting from AOT which states:

```
Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'AutoCompleteModule'
    'AutoCompleteModule' references 'ɵ4'
      'ɵ4' contains the error at ../index.js.ts(698,41)
        Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.
```

Here is the code in question (top line is the line referenced in the error message):

```
var AutoCompleteModule = /** @class */ (function () {
    function AutoCompleteModule() {
    }
    AutoCompleteModule_1 = AutoCompleteModule;
    AutoCompleteModule.forRoot = function () {
        return {
            ngModule: AutoCompleteModule_1,
            providers: []
        };
    };
    var AutoCompleteModule_1;
    AutoCompleteModule = AutoCompleteModule_1 = __decorate$1([
        NgModule({
            declarations: [
                AutoCompleteComponent,
                BoldPrefix
            ],
            exports: [
                AutoCompleteComponent,
                BoldPrefix
            ],
            imports: [
                CommonModule,
                FormsModule,
                IonicModule
            ]
        })
    ], AutoCompleteModule);
    return AutoCompleteModule;
}());

export { AutoCompleteComponent, AutoCompleteModule, AutoCompleteOptions, BoldPrefix };
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

I have tried removing arrow functions, I have tried removing decorators (ie `@class`, `@param`), I have tried changing rollup, I have tried tinkering with my tsconfig files, changing my imports, and much more.

Here are all of my imports:

```
import { Input, Output, ViewChild, ElementRef, HostListener, Component, EventEmitter, TemplateRef, Pipe, Injectable, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Platform, IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Subject, from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: You only have one source file in your project? Is there a git repo for this project?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the error was limited to the line, I have attached the github repo to question. https://github.com/jrquick17/ionic4-auto-complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in my generated dist files that my index.d.ts need to change from this:

```
export * from './auto-complete/auto-complete.component';
export * from './auto-complete.service';
export * from './bold-prefix.pipe';
export * from './auto-complete-options.model';
export declare class AutoCompleteModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders;
}
```

Into this:

```
import {NgModule, ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import {IonicModule} from '@ionic/angular';

import {AutoCompleteComponent} from './auto-complete/auto-complete.component';
import {BoldPrefix} from './bold-prefix.pipe';

export * from './auto-complete/auto-complete.component';
export * from './auto-complete.service';
export * from './bold-prefix.pipe';
export * from './auto-complete-options.model';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AutoCompleteComponent,
        BoldPrefix
    ],
    exports: [
        AutoCompleteComponent,
        BoldPrefix
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule
    ]
})
export declare class AutoCompleteModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders;
}
```

Though this works it seems more like a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

> Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'AutoCompleteModule'

Sadly, this error message is *completely* useless.

The only times I've seen this error raised is when there has been an *import* from the internals of a `node_modules` folder.

For example;

```js
import {concat} from 'rxjs/src/internal/observable/concat';
```

The above example imports source code that was not intended to be used, and what happens is inside that source code are declarations of TypeScript features such as decorators. These can get picked up by the Angular AOT compiler which raises the above error. The error is often thrown far away from where the offending import exists.

Since the AOT is turned off during development mode. The errors are silent.

So double check all of your imports.

Comment: I checked and even reimported all of my imports with any luck. Thanks for the help though.